# Adding elements programmatically to FrameLayout using a for loop

Tags: android

Why when I add the elements to the FrameLayout flCatScroll only one shows and not ten are they perhaps overlapping and or why dosn't the margin increase.

```
    myactivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Main Framelayout
            FrameLayout flCatScroll = (FrameLayout) myactivity.findViewById(R.id.flCatScroll);
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
            params.topMargin = 20;

            for(int i = 0;  i < 10; i++) {
                //FrameLayout mainItemLayout = new FrameLayout(myactivity);
                listFramelayouts.add(new FrameLayout(myactivity));
            }
            for(int i = 0;  i < listFramelayouts.size(); i++) {
                params.topMargin = 20 * i;
                TextView itemName = new TextView(myactivity);
                itemName.setText("Test" + i);
                listFramelayouts.get(i).addView(itemName);
                flCatScroll.addView(listFramelayouts.get(i), params);
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference semantics strike again!

Because you're reusing the params object instead of creating a new one each time, They all share the same margin at the end regardless of what the margin was when you added the view. So they are, indeed, all overlapping.

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 2):

dcow is right. You are reusing the same LayoutParams object for each new TextView. So at the end all of them have the same topMargin. You need to create params per each new view. You can add new function like:

```
    private FrameLayout.LayoutParams getLayoutParamsFor(final int i) {
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
        params.topMargin = 20 * i;
        return params;
    }
```

and then inside your loop you call it in addView(...) call:

```
    flCatScroll.addView(listFramelayouts.get(i), getLayoutParamsFor(i));
```